# in/out to Fragment Shader from Geometry Shader using GLES31 (#version 310 es)

Tags: opengl-es, shader, opengl-es-3.1

in/out to Fragment Shader from Geometry Shader using GLES31 (#version 310 es)

block interface is not supported, VS and FS in GLES31

And simply in/out like below

GS

```
out lowp float tmp;
void main()
{
tmp = sumValue;
}
```

FS

```
in lowp float tmp;
void main()
{
oColor = tmp * usingTmp;
}
```

Then, program is running, but color blink.

how to use in/out between GS and FS ?

Comment: [OpenGL ES 3.1](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/es/3.1/es_spec_3.1.pdf) (and 
GLSL `#version 310 es`) do not support geometry shaders. Geometry shaders are supported only in [OpenGL ES 3.2](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/es_spec_3.2.pdf#page=345&zoom=100,168,357) (GLSL `#version 320 es`) or with [EXT_geometry_shader](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_geometry_shader.txt)